# jQuery mobile listview multiple click event

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery, jquery-mobile-listview

I fill list dynamically, and after that on click I have multiple calls of event. 1st time it is repeated 1 time, 2nd time 2 times, 3rd time 3 times, etc...

Comment: what is your question? Could you show your code?

Comment: Show your code, for sure you are binding event inside an other handler

Comment: code is classified, event is triggered, but when I open the page for 2nd, or 3rd times, event is triggered 2 or 3 times.

Comment: And how could someone help you with the irrelevant information you posted in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, more about this problem can be found in my other answer: **[jQuery Mobile: document ready vs page events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)**

### Prevent multiple event binding/triggering

Because of interesting jQM loading architecture, multiple event triggering is a constant problem. For example, take a look at this code snipet:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow','#index' ,function(e,data){    
    $(document).on('click', '#test-button',function(e) {
        alert('Button click');
    });    
});
```

Working jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/CCfL4/

Each time you visit page **#index** click event will is going to be bound to button **#test-button**. There are few ways to prevent this problem:

**Solution 1:**

Remove event before you bind it:

```
$('#index').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){    
    $('#test-button').die().live('click', function(e) {
        alert('Button click');
    });    
});
```

Working jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/K8YmG/

In case you have different events bound to an object:

```
$('#index').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){    
    $('#test-button').die('click').live('click', function(e) {
        alert('Button click');
    });    
});
```

**Solution 2:**

Use a jQuery Filter selector, like this:

```
$('#carousel div:Event(!click)').each(function(){
    //If click is not bind to #carousel div do something
});
```

Because event filter is not a part of official jQuery framework it can be found here:   http://www.codenothing.com/archives/2009/event-filter/

In a nutshell, if speed is your main concern then **Solution 2** is much better then Solution 1.

**Solution 3:**

A new one, probably an easiest of them all.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    $(document).on('click', '#test-button',function(e) {
        if(e.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
        {
            alert('Clicked');
            e.handled = true;
        }
    }); 
});
```

Working jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Yerv9/

Tnx to the [sholsinger](http://www.gajotres.net/prevent-jquery-multiple-event-triggering/) for this solution: http://sholsinger.com/archive/2011/08/prevent-jquery-live-handlers-from-firing-multiple-times/

## More info

If you want to find more about this problem take a look at this **[article](http://www.gajotres.net/prevent-jquery-multiple-event-triggering/)**, working examples are included.

Comment: How about just using a different event for your outer event handler? `pageinit` should work. So that the inner event handler only gets bound on fresh DOM elements. This has been answered many times before, I think it behooves the SA community to link to existing answers rather than re-write them. Also, welcome to the 1K jQuery Mobile club :)